# Reordering issue in Staggered GridView Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I have an issue while using staggered GridView Layout. After I delete an element from the list, the item in the staggered gridview don't properly rearrange themselves. I mean, they leave lots of empty spaces above them.

Here are some pictures of before and after deleting,

before:

[image: PICTURE1]

after:

[image: PICTURE2]

one more:

[image: PICTURE3]

But after I close the app and open it again, they reorder themselves properly.

Here is my code,
Fragment:

```
public class TaskListFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = TaskListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private FragmentTaskListBinding mBinding;

private TaskViewModel viewModel;

private TaskListAdapter taskListAdapter;

private List<TaskEntity> entityList;

private StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager;

public TaskListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static TaskListFragment instantiate() {
    return new TaskListFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_task_list,
            container, false);
    mBinding.setFabClick(clickCallback);
    layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mBinding.taskListRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mBinding.taskListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    return mBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
            .get(TaskViewModel.class);
    subscribeUi(viewModel);
}

private void subscribeUi(TaskViewModel viewModel) {
    viewModel.loadTasks().observe(this, taskEntities -> {
        if (taskEntities != null) {
            setListData(taskEntities);
        }
    });
    mBinding.executePendingBindings();
}

private void setListData(List<TaskEntity> taskEntities) {
    this.entityList = taskEntities;
    taskListAdapter = new TaskListAdapter();
    taskListAdapter.setTaskList(entityList);
    mBinding.taskListRecyclerView.setAdapter(taskListAdapter);
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(createHelperCallback());
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mBinding.taskListRecyclerView);
}

private final FabClickCallback clickCallback = new FabClickCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFabClick() {
        if (getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
            ((MainListActivity) getActivity()).start();
        }
    }
};

private ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback createHelperCallback() {
    return new SwipeToDelete() {
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            viewModel.deleteTask(entityList.get(position));

            entityList.remove(position);
            taskListAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    };

}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class TaskListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskListAdapter.TaskViewHolder> {

private List<? extends Task> mTasks;

public TaskListAdapter() {
}

public void setTaskList(List<? extends Task> tasks) {
    if (mTasks == null) {
        mTasks = tasks;
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, mTasks.size());
    } else {
        DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return mTasks.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                return tasks.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return mTasks.get(oldItemPosition).getTId() ==
                        tasks.get(newItemPosition).getTId();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                Task newTask = tasks.get(newItemPosition);
                Task oldTask = mTasks.get(oldItemPosition);
                return newTask.getTId() == oldTask.getTId()
                        && Objects.equals(newTask.getTaskName(), oldTask.getTaskName())
                        && Objects.equals(newTask.getTaskDescription(), oldTask.getTaskDescription());
            }
        });
        mTasks = tasks;
        result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
}

@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    TaskItemBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.task_item,
            parent, false);
    return new TaskViewHolder(mBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mBinding.setTask(mTasks.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mTasks == null ? 0 : mTasks.size();
}

static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final private TaskItemBinding mBinding;

    public TaskViewHolder(TaskItemBinding taskItemBinding) {
        super(taskItemBinding.getRoot());
        mBinding = taskItemBinding;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `layoutManger.invalidateSpanAssignments()` just after `notifyItemRemoved` ?

Comment: You're welcome! btw which version of lib. you're using ?

Comment: Edit: the problem still appears to exist. I'm experiencing the same problem after a couple of tests. @Debdeep

Comment: maybe you could use a `Handler` to post the updates

Comment: I'll try that and let you know if it worked. Thank you for your quick responses. @Debdeep

Comment: Also make sure to update the support libraries above 22 :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found the answer to my problem.

I've been creating a new adapter over and over and setting it to the recyclerview in setListData() method instead of putting them in onCreateView method. Moving those two lines of code to onCreateView fixed my issue.